# Custom view filter

Tags: views

I need to add a custom (exposed?) filter to a view - it would query a large 'postcodes' table to find out coordidnates of postcodes accross the UK, and then perform a comparison of 2 postcodes (belonging to users) to find out the distance, and filter out users that are over a certain distance.

I've got the scripts to do this already, its just I'm really new to Drupal so the whole blocks/views/nodes/content types/filters thing is still confusing me a little.

Perhaps what I'm asking is beyond the scope of a filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is the [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) module, which integrates with Views and lets you do proximity searches. While not exactly what you want, [this handbook page](http://drupal.org/node/359463) should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand that may be possible with the [Views PHP Filter Module](http://drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter). There you can create a list of nid's that you want to intersect or remove from the views result. Take a look at the example [here](http://drupal.org/node/690670#comment-3353916).